# App store cancel button not working

Tags: ios, swift

So I have a button that opens the app store page for the app via "UIApllication.sharedApplication().openURL"

What is strange is that instead of popping up with a regular Web browser it opens to the app store page.

The problem is that there is a cancel button on the page it opens.  And that button does not seem to work. Any ideas how I might implement that button?

Here is the code: (vc() is just a function that returns the view controller)

```
static func rate()
    {
        crashLog("Opening up itunes page")
        //https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/toothache-be-the-monster/id1033405285?mt=8
        if let v = vc()
        {
            let url  = NSURL(string: "itms://itunes.apple.com/de/app/toothache-be-the-monster/id1033405285?mt=8&uo=4")
            if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url!) == true  {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
            }
        }
        neverRateAgain()
    }
```

Comment: What should the cancel button do?

Comment: Can we see the code where you open the app store

Comment: @123FLO321 I have added the code.

Comment: @J.Doe I have edited my answer. I hope it will solve your problem :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** Now that you added more code, let me show you how I achieved what you wanted to achieve.

**CODE:**

```
func showRateMe() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Would you like to rate the App?", message: "We hope you enjoy the App !", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Rate App now !", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { alertAction in
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string : "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/name/id")!)
        alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Later!", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { alertAction in
        alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "NO !", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { alertAction in
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "neverRate")
        alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }))
}
```

**SOLUTION (I think):**

I use in my code: `"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/name/id"`

You use in yours: `"itms://itunes.apple.com/de/app/toothache-be-the-monster/id1033405285?mt=8&uo=4"`

**Yours should be:** `"https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/toothache-be-the-monster/id1033405285?mt=8&uo=4"`

---

**OLD ANSWER THAT APPLIED TO A PREVIOUS VERSION OF THE QUESTION:**

If I am not mistaken, this is what you need to do:

1) Create a cancel button with an IBAction.

2) IBAction does this:

```
self.dismissViewController()
```

3) Done.

This is how I would "implement the Cancel button" as you wrote in your question.

Comment: I'm doing a spritekit app.  I don't know where to put an ibaction

Answer (score 2):

I testet your code.

The problem is that you are using **itms** which will open the iTunes Store.

Simpy use **itms-apps** instead of **itms** so it will be opened in the App Store rather then the iTunes Store.  (Don't forget to change it in you .plist too)

```
let url  = NSURL(string: "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/de/app/toothache-be-the-monster/id1033405285?mt=8&uo=4")
```